# Kendo UI for Angular 2: Excel export having multiple datasets

Tags: typescript, angular6, export-to-excel, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to merge two different kind of datasets in one single worksheet. One dataset is fixed spanning 10 rows. another dataset is large and will comprise of upto 1000 to 10000 records. The first dataset represent the metadata about the second dataset and is displayed above the second dataset in the excel sheet. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use approach similar to the one demonstrated [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/how-to/export-to-separate-sheets/) but instead of adding separate sheets, add the second sheet rows to the first one:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6ssfs?file=app/app.component.ts